# Sort media picker images in Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

I want to change the default image sorting of media picker from old -> new to new -> old (new images on the top) while selecting an image using media picker.

Comment: Post your code ..what have you been tried so far?

Comment: This is what I asked as I don't have an idea if this is even possible or not

Comment: It's been a few months since I've used Umbraco, but could you not sort the media library itself?

Comment: @MikeB how to do that?